# What is the adjective of "Tinder"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

What is the adjective from the noun "Tinder"? and what is more appropriate to use the adjective of "Tinder" or to use "Flammable" instead?

P.S: do you know any website that can convert any noun I put into it into an adjective and vice versa? I tried, but couldn't find one, if you know please mention it below.

Comment: Did you try a (monolingual) dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Not every noun has an "adjective form".  There are some adjectives that are formed from nouns: For example Bump -> Bumpy or Ocean -> Oceanic. Creating adjectives like "tindery" is possible but there are better options.

Many words don't have an adjective form. "Tinder", which means "the very light stuff that you can light with sparks from a flint", doesn't have a adjective that is closely related to it. A piece of wood is flammable, but it is not tinder.

You can always say "It is like tinder", or "as dry as tinder".

Comment: [*tindery*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tinder) is in this dictionary, but I would prefer something like "tinder-like".

Comment: *Tindery* and even *tinder-like* won't mean flammable, but that it looks and feels like tinder.  Tinder has multiple qualities other than being flammable, such as dry, disposable, etc. and *tindery* will carry all those qualities.